# Should "multi-boot" and "dual-boot" tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Should the [multi-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot) and [dual-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) tags be synonyms?  If not, when should I use one over the other?

I recently asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/664997/245988) and wasn't sure which tag would be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see why there should be multiple tags. [dual-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) should be a synonym of [multi-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot).

Comment: Considering the multi-boot tag info page is just one line, there doesn't seem to be a good reason why they shouldn't be synonyms.

Comment: dual-boot is just a special case of multi-boot.  However, many people use the dual-boot term.  So, yes they should be synonyms and should both be retained.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Are there any high-rep users that want to take care of this?